# Drag URL to a batch file in Windows to get it as an argument

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm creating a batch script to process URLs:

```
@echo off
set baseurl=http://example.com/xxx/xxx/page.aspx?job=
for /F "tokens=6 delims=/ " %%a in ("%1") do (
    set result=%baseurl%%%a
)
@echo %result%| clip
```

The URL passed into script as an argument, separated by some delimiter and one extracted token is concatenated with another URL. Then result is placed into clipboard. And everything works as expected when I use it from command line:

```
C:\script.cmd http://example.com/xxx/yyy/zzz/requiredToken/
```

But I want to create a shortcut to this script on the Windows taskbar and drag URL to it from browser to process. This works for files but not for URLs. So is there any way to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: You've only got five tokens, _(side by side delimiters count as only one)_!

Comment: @Compo, I'm splitting `%1` not the `%baseurl%`. However this is still offtopic. My question is how to pass URL using drag-n-drop.

Comment: @compo, no problem :) well, in this particular case i need only sixth token. I was too lazy to shorten the task to an abstract one.

Comment: Apologies, speed reading is a bad habit. Do you always want the sixth token from every URL dropped, _it seems a little restrictive. I would understand more if you wanted the last token_. Would having spaces as delimiters not mean that it would also be uncertain which token is propagated to `%result%` too.